# Charge that moves inside a conducting sphere

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a conducting sphere of charge Q and inside it we set a charge -q from the centre with initial velocity uo and i would like to know with what speed it reaches the surface of the sphere and what will be the maximum distance that will go through from the centre of the sphere.

Comment: Please try to specify the initial conditions better (where is the charge inside, what is $u_0$, how is $Q$ distributed?) and show us what you have done so far.

Comment: the Q is distributes in the surface because I have conducting sphere.However, I think that, because E=0 inside the sphere tha the charge will move with constant velocity because there is no force. I don't know however...

Comment: This is an interesting question.  I guess the sphere is hollow, so it is really a spherical shell.  How have you tried to solve this problem?  We expect you to do your best to solve it yourself before asking for help.  Please show what you've got so far.

Comment: I think that, because E=0 inside the sphere, the charge will move with constant velocity because there is no force. I don't know however...

Comment: Does the electric field inside the sphere still vanish if there is a charge inside?